# How to enable Android Open Application voice interaction

Tags: android, voice-recognition

According to the [system voice command docs](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/#open_actions), you can **open** an application with a voice command.  e.g. `OK Google - open foobar`.  Also according to the docs, this *Works by default; no specific intent.*
In my sample development app, this isn't working. I've tried adding a few combinations of action and category permutations to the intent-filter, but no luck so far.
I'm targeting a minimum SDK of 23, testing on a device with 6.0.1.

Should this work, and if so, what are the changes to a new empty activity project I need to enable it?

Comment: Does it work when you say `open clock` or another phonetic sounding currently installed application?

Comment: Yes.  Most other popular applications do work.  Some don't though, which is what makes me think it takes some coding to enable.

Comment: I edited my answer to include 'open' before the application name. I assume you spotted that mistake though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Google simply iterates over a list of installed applications and opens the corresponding application if it finds an **exact match**.

To test this, use the following [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
        final String PACKAGE_NAME_GOOGLE_NOW = "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox";
        final String GOOGLE_NOW_SEARCH_ACTIVITY = ".SearchActivity";
        final String APP_NAME = "Open " +getString(R.string.app_name);

        final Intent startMyAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        startMyAppIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(PACKAGE_NAME_GOOGLE_NOW,
                PACKAGE_NAME_GOOGLE_NOW + GOOGLE_NOW_SEARCH_ACTIVITY));

        startMyAppIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, APP_NAME);
        startMyAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            startActivity(startMyAppIntent);
        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If this opens your application, then it is simply a case of the phonetics of your application name, or how Google interprets your pronunciation of it.

I do think that there should be an option to add a 'phonetic app label' to the application's manifest (or some other globally available configuration file), so Google could open your application if the unique name is not common enough to generate a voice search result.

If this doesn't open your application, check that you are correctly defining your application name in the manifest as follows:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Thanks brandall - it being an exact match looks to be the requirement.