# Open another application in android using voice commands?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

So I am trying to develop an application which uses voice recognition to handle a lot of events like calling any phone number, opening other applications, toggle settings, etc.

What i have done till now is implementing the calling feature, the place where i am stuck is how to open another applications

My code till now is :

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech Prompt");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT : {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                String arr[] = result.get(0).split(" ",2);
                String firstWord = arr[0];
                String secondWord = arr[1];
                switch(firstWord) {
                    case "call":
                        callPhone(secondWord);
                        break;
                    case "open":


                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see i can use case "open" as first word and then continue with it. But i don't have any idea how to get the list of all apps installed currently on the phone.
Kindly help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get list of all application/activities installed on the device:

```
final Intent Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
Intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List<ResolveInfo> packageAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(Intent, 0);
```

get your relevant data to open the apps on ResolveInfo, read more below:

```
for (ResolveInfo res : packageAppsList ){
    //print it to logger etc.
    res.loadLabel(getPackageManager().toString();
```

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html

Comment: `ResolveInfo{151f1374 com.snapchat.android/.LandingPageActivity m=0x108000}` . The List packageAppsList contains various tuples such as the one cited above. How should i extract the applications name from this information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that edit. It solved my query perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Related question: [How to enable Android Open Application voice interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765978/how-to-enable-android-open-application-voice-interaction)

Cited from there: "As far as I am aware, Google simply iterates over a list of installed applications and opens the corresponding application if it finds an exact match."

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the link although I had already seen that. What I want is something that SearchManager does but in my own app. Right now it first opens google now then shows the result and then asks whether you want to open it or not.