# Problems with "Open Application" voice action

Tags: android, google-play-services, voice-recognition, voice

Is there any specific actions that developers should do to support "Open App" Google Now command? Documentation says that we do not need to do any additional actions to support this feature, but with my app there is no hope. I have even tried to change app name to something similar, like "cat" or "dog", but there was no result anyway. Also, if we specify the exact intent for search, other apps (Pinterest, Facebook or Instagram) could be opened as expected, while my not.

Comment: You can try using the code implementation in the related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37776726/5995040) by putting an intent and checking the exact match to open the app. Also stated that most apps works in the "open application" and some don't.

Comment: Thank you, @Mr.Rebot, but I have already tried this and nothing changed. Interesting thing - Android opens app normally while device has no connection.