# is it possible to create an android app which open via certain fix words of voice password?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to create an android app which open via certain fix word of voice password? If it is possible please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch an android app from the voice like OK Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317130/how-to-launch-an-android-app-from-the-voice-like-ok-google)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Android Open Application voice interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765978/how-to-enable-android-open-application-voice-interaction)

Comment: okay thanks i will try